# MySQL Query for subtracting values from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Hello I have this tables

```
Table A
ID  Name   Price QTY
1   name1  1000  10
2   name2  1200  5

Table B
ID  Name   Price QTY
1   name1  1000  2
```

I want to achieve

```
Table C
ID  Name   Price QTY
1   name1  1000  8
2   name2  1200  5
```

With my query `SELECT DISTINCT ta.name, ta.price,(ta.quantity - tb.quantity) AS quantity, FROM TableA AS ta INNER JOIN TableB AS tb ON ta.id = tb.id`

What I get is this

```
Table C
ID  Name   Price QTY
1   name1  1000  8
2   name2  1200  3
```

I sorry I really cant think of a way how to achieve what I want. Thanks for your help.

Comment: SELECT ta.ID, ta.NAME, ta.Price, (ta.QTY - IFNULL(tb.QTY, 0)) AS QTY FROM TableA AS ta LEFT JOIN Table2 AS tb ON ta.id = tb.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query actually gets you one line instead of two:

```
-- result set
# name, price, quantity
name1, 1000, 8
```

Based on your expected output,we can use:

```
SELECT  ta.ID, ta.name, ta.price, ifnull((ta.QTY - tb.QTY),ta.QTY) AS quantity 
FROM TableA AS ta 
LEFT JOIN TableB AS tb 
ON ta.name = tb.name and ta.price=tb.price;
-- result set:
# ID, name, price, quantity
1, name1, 1000, 8
2, name2, 1200, 5
```

This is the last updated answer I can give you for you updated request.Please consider firing a new question if it does not fulfill.

```
-- Supposing your latest tables have the following data.
insert TableA values
(1 ,  'name1' , 1000 , 10)
,(2 ,  'name2' , 1200 , 5);
insert TableB values
(1 ,  'name1' , 1000 , 2),
(2 , 'name2', 1000 , 3)
;

-- You probably want this:
SELECT ta.ID, ta.name, ta.price, ifnull((ta.QTY - tb.QTY),ta.QTY) AS quantity 
FROM TableA AS ta 
LEFT JOIN TableB AS tb 
ON ta.name = tb.name and ta.price=tb.price
union
SELECT  Id , name , price , QTY 
from TableB t
where not exists (select * from TableA where t.name=name and t.price=price)
;

-- result set:
# ID, name, price, quantity
1, name1, 1000, 8
2, name2, 1200, 5
2, name2, 1000, 3
```

Comment: What if my table A has this data

`Table B
ID  Name   Price QTY
1   name1  1000  2
2  name2. 1000  3`

The result I get is 
`# ID, name, price, quantity
1, name1, 1000, 8
1, name1, 1000, 7
2, name2, 1200, 5`

What I want is
`# ID, name, price, quantity
1, name1, 1000, 5
2, name2, 1200, 5`

Comment: What do you mean by 'What if my table A has this data' ? Could you elaborate ?

Comment: Im sorry I cant edit anymore I think it looks confusing... I cant make it look like a table...

Comment: I inserted into TableB with values (2 , 'name2', 1000 , 3) and got the following:# ID, name, price, quantity
1, name1, 1000, 8
2, name2, 1200, 2

Comment: Please check your data. Something is definitely amiss. I have been using the data you provided and it works fine for me.

Comment: but basically what I want to do is table a qty minus table b qty that has same price and name and other name with no same price with table b or table a will maintain its qty value...

Comment: I also think so too... I really need help what I posted is a simple way to represent what I want but I think there is really something wrong with what Im doing. Is there a way I can show it to you? Verry appreciate your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247276/discussion-between-blabla-bingo-and-chadson).

Comment: So you want to change the join condition to make it based on name and price . That's actually more reasonable than you original query which joins on id. I shall update the answer. But please try not to update your request again.

Comment: If the updated answer still eludes you. Please consider opening another thread and fully explain the case in one go.